# How do I "json_decode" a single column data after fetch from database in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I am saving an array in one column of my database using `json_encode` as follows and it works:

```
    $service->description = $request->service_description;
    $service->image = json_encode($url);
    $service->duration = $request->service_delivery_time;
```

When I fetch the data I get a string. I am fetching using `$service = Service::findOrFail($id);`. I can decode the individual column as done below and pass it to the view.

```
    $service = Service::findOrFail($id);
    $images = json_decode($service->image);
    return view('services.show',['service'=>$service , 'images'=>$images]);
```

What I am asking is, can I decode the images in one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use $cast or Accessor

1: $cast:

```
protected $casts = [
'image' => 'array'];
```

2: Accessor:

```
public function getImageAttribute()
{
    return json_decode($this->attributes['image']);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Well this is a single query, `json_decode` runs after the SQL query returned your desired result.

What you can do is add a `$casts` property to your `Service` model so Laravel encodes/decodes it automatically for you, then you don't need to store these values with `json_encode`, just do `$service->image = $url`, and when you run `findOrFail`, the `image` property will already be a decoded json.

```
protected $casts = [
    'image' => 'array',
];
```

[Here's the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting)